# Chung's A Course in Probability Theory, exercise 3.1.4

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Prove:

Let $\theta$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.
For each d.f. $F$, define $G(y)$ $=$ $sup\{x:F(x)\le y\}$.
Then, $G(\theta)$ has the d.f. $F$.

1. What is the exact definition of $\theta$ ?

I assume it is a r.v., from probability space $([0,1], \Bbb B[0,1], m)$ to $(\Bbb R^1, \Bbb B^1 , \mu)$ where $m$ is a regular Borel measure, and for each $w \in [0,1], \theta(w) = w$. Is it correct?

2. Is this proof ok?

$m(G(\theta) \le x) = m(sup\{t: F(t) \le \theta\} \le x)$.

$sup\{t: F(t) \le \theta\} \le x$ $\iff$ $(F(t) \le \theta \Rightarrow t \le x)\iff$ $(x < t \Rightarrow \theta < F(t)\,)$

$\iff\theta \le F(x)$ if $F(x) = F(t)$ for some $t$ , or $\theta < F(x)$ if not.

($\because $ F is right-continuous, and $\lim \limits_{t \to x+} F(t) = F(x)$)

In each cases, $m(G(\theta) \le x) = F(x)$.

Comment: It means that for every Borel set $A \subset [0,1], P(\theta \in A) = m(A)$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: If I prove that the distribution function of $\theta$ is equal to identical function, i.e., 
$F(x) = P(\theta \le x) = x $ is it sufficient to say that $\theta$ is a uniformly distributed?

Comment: Yes it is because the uniform distribution has that CDF and, by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, two probability measures with the same CDF are equal.